# AuthSub nextURL on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authsub

I am looking at
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html
and
http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/articles/java/retrieving_gdata_feeds.html.

My code looks like this to generate the URL

```
String nextUrl = "http://myapp.appspot.com/retrieveToken/";
String scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/";
boolean secure = false;  // set secure=true to request secure AuthSub tokens
boolean session = true;
String authSubUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(nextUrl, scope, secure, session);
```

The generated url looks like this

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.appspot.com%2FretrieveToken%2F&scope=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Ffeeds%2F&secure=0&session=1
```

Looks good..
However when i follow the URL i am told something along the lines of

```
"http://appspot.com" is not registered.
```

(i get it in swedish :)

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's odd because because you choosed `secure = false`, so you shouldn't have to register the application (you have `secure=0` in your URL). But I feel that it is an issue related to the `*.appspot.com` domain, because if you change the `nextUrl` to anything else, let's say `"http://myapp.randomDomainHjYHBB4F.com/retrieveToken/"`, the new URL is:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest?next=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.randomDomainHjYHBB4F.com%2FretrieveToken%2F&scope=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Ffeeds%2F&secure=0&session=1
```

... and it works! Isn't it very curious?

So I can't tell you what's wrong but there is an easy workaround: you can [register your application](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html) and [switch to secure mode](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html#register)!